# Stored procedure to update row from another table

Tags: sql, join, stored-procedures, datatable, sql-update

The point is to update**(change from 0 to 1)** the roster table(week 1, week 2, ....week 16) for John doe from MHS when he checks in with his phone number. The apptable captures the checkin date in created date column which should equal week 1 date from week date table.

The roster table should not update if John doe should try to check in from JHS.
See image for clarity and details
Current state: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18o5J.png)
Expected result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUkcT.png)

Roster table(Current State)

```
UID   Name      School   Participant1phone   Participant2phone   Week1   Week2 
1     John Doe  MHS      8324444444          8325555555          0       0 
2     Nia Long  JHS      6785555555          6784444444          0       0
```

Weekdate table:

```
SchoolUID School  Week1      Week2 
1         MHS     9/7/2020   9/14/2020 
2         JHS     9/8/2020   9/15/2020
```

Roster Table(Expected Result after check in)

```
UID Name        School  Participant1phone   Participant2phone   Week1   Week2
1   John Doe    MHS     8324444444          8325555555          1       1
2   Nia Long    JHS     6785555555          6784444444          1       1
```

App table

```
ID  Userphonenumber     Created on
1   8324444444          9/7/2020
2   6785555555          9/15/2020
```

Here is the sql query so far:

```
create procedure updtroster 
AS
begin
    update roster 
    set roster.week = 1
    from apptable a
    left join roster on a.UserPhoneNumber = roster.Participant1phone
end;
```

Comment: Please can you share with us what database do you use ?

Comment: I'd guess SQL Server. But could perhaps be Sybase too.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, no images.) And take a look at [mcve] first pf all.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong but I have assumed you are using SQLServer...

This is the way you can do the update statement when you want to update one table based on the data from the other table:

```
update roster 
set roster.week = 1
from apptable a
left join roster on a.UserPhoneNumber = roster.Participant1phone;
```

And having that then it is easy to put it in the procedure:

```
create procedure updtroster 
AS
begin
    update roster 
    set roster.week = 1
    from apptable a
    left join roster on a.UserPhoneNumber = roster.Participant1phone;
end;
```

As you can see I have added only the join condition that I have understood from your question. You can add this other condition too, if you need it. You can put it in the where clause and then the update statement would look like this:

```
    update roster 
    set roster.week = 1
    from apptable a
    left join roster on a.UserPhoneNumber = roster.Participant1phone
    where roster.some_column = getdate();
```

Here is the demo where I have created two tables just for test purpose. Then I have tested the update statement and after that I have tested the procedure.

> > [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ceb0f3cfc274aed043b6e6f48ac11328)

Comment: Thanks vboka. This was very helpful. and yes. I'm using sql. If there are 16 weeks(16 columns) in the destination table, do I just repeat the same update query for all 16 weeks? The thing is, all 16 weeks has different dates which is another table(weekdate table). How do I connect this in the query.

Comment: Thanks vboka. This was very helpful. and yes. I'm using sql. If there are 16 weeks(16 columns) in the destination table, do I just repeat the same update query for all 16 weeks? The thing is, all 16 weeks has different dates which is another table(weekdate table). How do I connect this in the where statement of the update query? For example, if week 1 date in dbo.weekdate= 9/7/2020 but john doe can check in any weekday within 9/7 week, how do I write that section of the query?

Comment: Hi @OBB,well.. you see, the thing is I do not understand what is this for and why(why do you update the column and for what reasuon/in what conditions). It would be great to understand this and then  more people can helpy you. One way to understand your problem better is for you to give us example data for all of this 3 tables (only 3-4 rows of data per table) and with that also share with us expected results after the update statement.

Comment: I have made edits to the original question. *see above*Please let me know if I need to clarify some more.

Comment: Hi @OBB , you need to: 1. Add table data as text not as image. 2. Add data for the apptable 3. Add the data from the tabler roster as you expect it to be after the update procedure...

Comment: hi @vboka, how do I do this? I tried copying and pasting the excel into the question box but it keeps importing it as an image.

Comment: Hi, try to paste it to a text editor and then here ....

Comment: Weekdate table   
SchoolUID School Week 1 Week 2
1                 MHS 9/7/2020  9/14/2020
2                 JHS         9/8/2020 9/15/2020                                                    Roster table(Current State)      
UID Name School Participant1phone Participant2phone Week 1 Week 2
1 John Doe MHS 8324444444         8325555555               0 0
2 Nia Long JHS         6785555555         6784444444               0 0

Comment: Roster Table(Expected Result after check in)      
UID Name School Participant1phone Participant2phone Week 1 Week 2
1 John Doe MHS 8324444444 8325555555 1 1
2 Nia Long JHS 6785555555 6784444444 1 1                                            App table  
ID Userphonenumber Created on
1 8324444444         9/7/2020
2 6785555555         9/15/2020 @vboka, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi @OBB I have entered this tables into your question but I am not sure if it is still clear. As you can see your question is closed and I have voted to reopen it so maybe others will see that and maybe they will reopen. Until then lets try to help your question some more. Can you explain the situation you have imagined ? Person John Doe check's in WHEN ? HOW does he check's in ? Also, in your query you have this part: "from apptable" that means that you should have a table in your database with name apptable ? Is this true?

Comment: Yes. I have included the app table in the original question and image. Just don't know how to format it like you did. And yes, John doe checks in on 9/7/2020 from an app on his phone using a QR scan Code. The data populates into the app table but the goal is to update the roster from (0 to 1) to say that john doe has checked in for week 1 with a match on apptable.createddate=weeekdatetable.week1. I want to follow the same process for all of the 16 weeks in the roster table. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Hi @OBB, sorry but it makes it little bit more clear but not 100% clear. I suggest to unmark the correct answer from my answer because in that way you are telling to other people that your question is resolved and that you do not need any more help...

Comment: Hi @OBB I have also created a fiddle for your question you can add to your question: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae745a86cc64704800fd68ee582f01d6 this will help others help you...

Comment: i posted a similar issue here. can you please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698573/update-column-from-one-to-many-join-with-datetime